# Query is not returing value as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to take count of specific column i.e col1 from table 'TABLE1'.

Below is the query which i am hitting

```
select count(col1) into col_data
 from (SELECT TABLE_NAME from USER_TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'table1');
```

And following error i am getting

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select count(COL1) from (SELECT TABLE_NAME from USER_TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1')
Error at Command Line:1 Column:13
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "COL1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

NOTE: Please let me know how to use a variable with  from clause

Comment: Your sub-query returns TABLE_NAME column only, but you're trying to select col1.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for reply, But the actual problem is I am trying to get the count of 'COL1' from TABLE1 .but the from clause does not allow me to use a variable . That is the reason i am using subquery with from clause.

Please let me know if you have any better way to do this

Comment: @anurag If you're trying to get all the column names from a certain table and count them, you should use USER_TAB_COLUMNS. Is that what you want to do? I'm not sure I understood your question

Comment: @pablomatico I am trying to get the count of records in column col1 in table table1.

Comment: @anurag the count of records will be the same for every column. A record has values for each column of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of values in column col1 of table TABLE1 then u should write

```
select count(col1) from TABLE1 ;
```

If you want to make it generic so that you can do this count for any TABLE and COLUMN , and want to provide details at run time you can use the following

```
create or replace function get_count(table_name varchar2 , column_name varchar2)
return number
is
cnt number ;
begin
execute immediate 'select count('||column_name||') from '||table_name into     cnt ;
return cnt;
exception when others then
return 0;
end get_count;
```

Once u create this function in your schema u can do something like

```
select get_count('EMP' , 'EMP_ID') from dual ;
```

Comment: Thanks bud, I was looking somethin like this <execute immediate 'select count('||column_name||') from '||table_name into cnt ;>, it worked.